# For-loop and output

Tags: java, for-loop

This is a homework question that I cannot figure out. It's in Java.

Suppose we want to write a for loop that produces the following
nine lines of output:

```
 4:
 8:
12:
16:
20:
24:
28:
32:
36:
```

Suppose we will use the following for-loop to produce the output:

```
int index;
for (index = __A__; __B__ ; __C__ ) {
    System.out.printf(__D__, index);
}
```

Answer what should be in the four blanks in each of the following for the code?

1. _ _ *A* _ _
2. _ _ *B* _ _
3. _ _ *C* _ _
4. _ _ *D* _ _

Comment: What's the first value? how much are the values incremented by each loop? What is the last value?

Answer (score 2):

```
int index;
for (index = __A__; __B__ ; __C__ ) {
    System.out.printf(__D__, index);
}
```

If you see the output, the number (index) starts with 4.

Therefore, A : 4

It ends at 36.

Therefore, B : index<=36

It increases by 4.

Therefore, C : index+=4

Printed line's format is D : "%2d:\n"

Answer (score 0):

This for loop will give you the answer:

```
for (index=4; index<=36; index+=4) {
    System.out.printf(":\n"+ index);
}
```

A is index = 4

B is index<=36

C is index+=4

D is ":\n"

Make the print statement as:

```
System.out.printf(index + ":\n");
```

Now you will get the exact answer you expect.